# Is it possible to rename the files after copying from source folder?

Tags: vb.net

I copy some test images from source folder.. but i want to make their image name become "**001,002**" .. and so on.

```
        For Each path As ListViewItem In listbat1.Items 
        For Each Ftif As String In Directory.GetFiles(path.SubItems(0).Text, "*.tif")

            'For n As Integer = 0 To listbat1.Items.Count - 1

            Dim Finfo As New FileInfo(Ftif)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Ftif, txtdirectory.Text & imgdir & Finfo.Name & ".tif")

            'Next
        Next
    Next
```

Is it possible ? if so, can you help me? pls ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rename your file using a progressive counter, then you could easily do it using the ToString with a formatting expression. In this example  D3 means convert the input number to a string using three numbers and padding with zero if the number is not converted to enough character.

```
Dim counter as Integer = 0
For Each path As ListViewItem In listbat1.Items 
    For Each Ftif As String In Directory.GetFiles(path.SubItems(0).Text, "*.tif")

        Dim Finfo As New FileInfo(Ftif)
        Dim destFile = Path.Combine(txtDirectory.Text, imgdir, counter.ToString("D3") + ".tif")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Ftif, destFile)
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
Next
```

Notice also that building a path should always be done using the Path class

Comment: sorry for late response.. 

I get an error at the end of this code. something like .. expression ")"

`Dim destFile = Path.Combine(txtDirectory.Text, imgdir, counter.ToString("D3") + ".tif"`

Comment: Forgot the closing parenthesys

Comment: And it works ! ..

`For Each path1 As ListViewItem In listbat1.Items  Dim destFile = Path.Combine(txtdirectory.Text, imgdir & counter.ToString("D3") & ".tif")`  


Thanks a lot !. :)

Comment: I just change the `path1` cause i got an error at `path.combine` statement